# Why doesn't my engine rev up when closing choke valve?

Tags: engine, ford, fuel-system, carburetor, mustang

So I just installed a manual choke cable on my Mustang 1967 (Holley carb 4 bbl), and upon startup I pull the choke and see the valve close but the engine does not rev up at all. I go as much as to close the valve almost completely and try not to stall the engine from air restriction but the darn thing does not rev up at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the manual choke connected to a fast Idle cam ?

Comment: Is the engine cold when you've tested it?

Comment: 1. No it is not connected to a fast idle cam. 2. Yes I tried everything while cold and hot as well, no change whatsoever.

Comment: Is this the original carburetor setup on a stock engine or replacement? When cfactory chokes are used, the extra block off plate forces  enriched fuel mixtures for cold engine starting. Most if not all factory carbs use linkages between choke mechanisms and throttle plate to open throttle, preventing  fuel enrichment from stalling engines during cold engine warm ups. Old school carbs required at least one step on the gas pedal to engage a spring loaded configuration of choke and throttle opening before starting. Once engine runs, choke opens and throttle return to normal idle.